# OpenStreetView or points from CSV but not both showing?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm using QGIS on Mac (most recent version) and am trying to map coordinates from a csv file. When I import the file normally without having any base map, the coordinates how up distributed like I want. When I put a base map like Google Street View and then add the coordinates, the coordinates don't show up anywhere. Instead, I get a dot in the middle of the map (off the coast of Africa). What's the reason for this? I was told to use Pseudo Mercator EPSG:3857 WGS 84. I've tried using different projections as well.

I am using longitude/latitude coordinates. For either OpenStreetView or Google Street View, the same issue is happening.

Comment: Are the CSV file coordinates in latitude/longitude, or something else (UTM, feet, etc)?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to clarify whether you are using [OpenStreetView](http://openstreetview.org/) or Google's StreetView, please?  Your title seems to contradict your question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are not using OpenStreetView or GoogleStreetView inside QGIS, but the Openstreetmap layer and Google satellite layer provided by the openlayers plugin.

For that, **project** CRS **must** be in EPSG:3857.

If you have coordinates in lat/long, you have to add a layer with **layer** CRS set to EPSG:4326, and "On-the-Fly-Reprojection" enabled. Then the coordinates get automatically reprojected to the right place in EPSG:3857.

It might be helpful to go to `Settings -> Options -> CRS`, and set `Prompt for CRS` for new layers. Otherwise your csv table might be assigned to the project CRS without further notice, which is definitely wrong for lat/long coordinates.